# PHP - building html buttons with a loop

Tags: php, html, loops, button

I am a beginner developer and very new to php.

I am writing a php script for a webpage that displays the contents of a database in a table using a loop to build the table. Displaying the contents is not the problem, what I need to be able to do is have buttons for editing and deleting the coresponding row of the database on each row of the display table. So far my code builds the table and the buttons fine but I have know idea how I add the functionality to the buttons! for the edit button I need it to bring the user and the contents of that row to another page (already created) for editing, and the delete button just has to delete that row from the database. heres the code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>
          <td><select multiple class='form-control'><option>" . $row[3] . "</option></select></td>
          <td><center>" . $row[1] . "</center></td>
          <td><center>" . $row[7] . "</center></td>
          <td><center><img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' alt='' src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . $row[8] . "'/></center></td>
          <td><center><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Edit</button></center></center>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><center><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></center></td>
          </tr>";

}
```

I do not know how I will relate each button that gets built by the loop with the row that it is located on. Can anyone shine a light on this problem? Am I approaching this wrong maybe?

Thank you for any input!

Comment: I will recoment using jQuery and Ajax to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a lot easier if you use links instead of buttons, since you can then add values to the query string.  Something like this:

```
<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $row[0] . "\">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row[0] . "\">Delete</a></td>
```

This is assuming that `$row[0]` contains the identifier for the record, of course.  Use whatever identifier you need to use.  This would create links such as:

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="delete.php?id=1">Delete</a></td>
```

This allows the `edit.php` and `delete.php` pages to know which record is being edited or deleted.  Consider your statement:

> I need it to bring the user and the contents of that row to another page

A link brings a user to another page.  You can *style* the link to *look like* a button, but if you're "bringing a user to another page" then the markup you want is a link.  And you don't "bring the contents of that row" to the other page, you just supply that other page with an identifier so it can fetch that data from the database.  That other page would get the identifier from:

```
$_GET['id']
```

That identifier determines the record being edited or deleted.  So both the `edit.php` and `delete.php` pages would validate that value, ensure the user is permitted to perform that operation for that record, fetch that record, and render the page accordingly.

**Note:** Keep in mind that, for UX purposes, you can also treat the "other page" as an AJAX resource.  The delete functionality, for example, can be a normal "button" with a client-side JavaScript handler.  That handler can make an AJAX request to `delete.php` which does all the same functionality described above, but returns only JSON data instead of a whole page.  That data could be as simple as a boolean indicator of success or failure.

The JavaScript handler would make the AJAX request, receive the response, and if the response indicates success it would remove that row from the table in the UI.  Same structure, same functionality, just using AJAX instead of a page request.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i used the href/GET method and it works perfectly! thanks for helping further my understanding of php

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery/AJAX if you'd like, but I don't recommend it, since there are ways of doing that only using HTML:

One is using links instead of buttons, as you've been already told: that is to me the best solution, since it's easy to implement, and also looks better (but you could get the same look using some CSS, so not really a good point).

But, if you really need to use buttons, there are ways of doing that as well: the first one that comes to mind is using different forms for every row, and then add, in every row, a hidden input specifying an ID to use in your PHP script:

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method='POST'>
  AAA <input type='submit' value='Edit'><input type='hidden' name='edit' value='AAA'><br>
</form>
<form method='POST'>
  BBB <input type='submit' value='Edit'><input type='hidden' name='edit' value='BBB'><br>
</form>
<form method='POST'>
  CCC <input type='submit' value='Edit'><input type='hidden' name='edit' value='CCC'><br>
</form>
```

Not elegant, I know, but that's the first thing I came up with. Anyway, unless you really want the buttons, your code would probably look better if you decided to go with link!